# Troubleshooting hanged UDP socket in a Python server application code

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, udp

I am writing a UDP server application that serves as a back end to Teltonika FMB630 car mounted devices.

I already took care of the protocol specifics and decoding, the problem I am facing relates to the UDP socket used.

My UDP server has to send an acknowledgement to the client device upon receiving a message (that is the protocol), however, if I send those ACKs, the server socket stops receiving data after a while.

The server's UDP socket object is passed to an `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` that fires a function (`send_ack`) that sends the ACK, however this is not the issue because I tried calling `send_ack` in the main thread, after receiving data and the same issue occurs.

I suspect the problem is the remote device somehow breaks the connection or the ISP or MNO doesn't route the reply packet (this is a GPRS device) and then the `socket.send()` method that is used to send the acknowledge, somehow freezes other socket operations, specifically `recvfrom_into` called in the main thread loop.

I wrote two scripts to illustrate the situation:

**udp_test_echo.py :**

```
#!/usr/env/bin python

import socket
import concurrent.futures

def send_ack(sock, addr, ack):
    print("Sending ACK to {}".format(addr))
    sock.connect(addr)
    print("connected to {}".format(addr))
    sock.send(ack)
    print("ACK sent to {}".format(addr))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1337))
data = bytearray([0] * 10)

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

while True:
    print("listening")
    nbytes, address = s.recvfrom_into(data)
    print("Socket Data received {} bytes Address {}".format(nbytes, address))
    print("Data received: ", data, " Echoing back to client")
    executor.submit(send_ack, s, address, data[:nbytes])
```

**udp_test_client.py:**

```
#!/usr/env/bin python

import socket
import time
import random

def get_random_bytes():
    return bytearray([random.randint(0,255) for b in range(10)])

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1337
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((ip, port))

while True:
    stuff_to_send = get_random_bytes()
    print("Sending stuff", stuff_to_send)
    s.sendall(stuff_to_send)
    print("reply: ", s.recvfrom(10))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Running udp_test_echo.py in one terminal and udp_test_client.py in another, we see normal operation but if you Ctrl+C the test client and re run it, you will see that the server doesn't respond until it is restarted.

Is there a way to timeout a specific sending operation from a specific call to `socket.send()` method without affecting other calls ? (I **want** my `socket.recvfrom_into` call to block on the main thread)

If I `settimeout` on the entire socket object, I am going to have to deal with many exceptions while waiting for data in the main thread and I don't like to have to rely on exceptions for proper program operation.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was the `socket.connect()` call in `send_ack`, when being called on the server's socket object it causes the socket to no longer be bound and listen on the port specified in the start of the program.

Instead the `send_ack` function was changed to be:

```
def send_ack(sock, addr, ack):
    print("Sending ACK to {}".format(addr))
    sock.sendto(ack, addr)
    print("ACK sent to {}".format(addr))
```

**socket.sendto(data, address)** uses the existing connection instead of starting a new one.